# Retrieve superior hash-key name in Hiera

Tags: puppet, hiera

Hallo I am building in Hiera / Puppet a data structure for creating mysql / config files. My goal ist to have some default values which can be overwritten with a merge. It works until this point.
Because we have different mysql instances on many hosts I want to automaticly configure some paths to be unique for every instance. I have the instance name as a hash (name) of hashes in the Namespace: our_mysql::configure_db::dbs:

In my case I want to lookup the instance names like "sales_db' or 'hr_db' in paths like datadir, but I can not find a way to lookup the superior keyname.

Hiera data from "our_mysql" module represents some default values:

```
our_mysql::configure_db::dbs:
  'defaults':
    datadir:     /var/lib/mysql/"%{lookup('lookup to superior hash-key name')}"
    log_error:   /var/log/mysql/"%{lookup('lookup to superior hash-key name')}".log
    logbindir:   /var/lib/mysql/"%{lookup('lookup to superior hash-key name')}"
    db_port:     3306
    ...:         ...
    KEY_N:       VALUE_N
```

Hiera data from node definiton:

```
our_mysql::configure_db::dbs:
  'sales_db':
    db_port: "3317"
    innodb_buffer_pool_size: "1"
    innodb_log_file_size: 1GB
    innodb_log_files_in_group: "2"
    server_id: "1"
  'hr_db':
    db_port: "3307"
```

I now how to do simple lookups or to iterate by
`.each | String $key, Hash $value | { ... }`

but I have no clue how to reference a key from a certain hierarchy level. Searching all related topics to puppet and hiera didn't help.

Is it possible an any way and if yes how?

Comment: This is done automatically by setting the hierarchy in your hiera configs. Please share all relevant `hiera.yaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question, I think what you hope to achieve is that, for example, when you look up `our_mysql::configure_db::dbs.sales_db` key, you get a merge of the data for that (sub)key and those for the `our_mysql::configure_db::dbs.defaults` subkey, **AND** that the various `%{lookup ...}` tokens in the latter somehow resolve to the string `sales_db`.

I'm afraid that's not going to happen.  The interpolation tokens don't even factor in here -- Hiera simply won't perform such a merge at all.  I guess you have a hash-merge lookup in mind, but that merges only identical keys and subkeys, so not `our_mysql::configure_db::dbs.sales_db` and `our_mysql::configure_db::dbs.defaults`.  Hiera provides for defaults for particular keys in the form of data recorded *for those specific keys* at a low-priority level of the data hierarchy.  The "defaults" subkey you present, on the other hand, has no special meaning to the standard Hiera data providers.

You can still address this problem, just not entirely within the data.  For example, consider this:

```
$dbs = lookup('our_mysql::configure_db::dbs', Hash, 'deep')

$dbs.filter |$dbname, $dbparms| { $dbname != 'defaults' }.each |$dbname, $dbparms| {
    # Declare a database using a suitable resource type.  "my_mysql::database" is
    # a dummy resource name for the purposes of this example only
    my_mysql::database {
      $dbname:
        * => $dbparams;
      default:
        datadir   => "/var/lib/mysql/${dbname}",
        log_error => "/var/log/mysql/${dbname}.log",
        logbindir => "/var/lib/mysql/${dbname}",
        *         => $dbs['defaults'];
    }
}
```

That supposes data of the form presented in the question, and it uses the data from the `defaults` subkey where those do not require knowledge of the specific DB name, but it puts the patterns for various directory names into the resource declaration, instead of into the data.  The most important things to recognize are the use of the splat `*` parameter wildcard for obtaining multiple parameters from a hash, and the use per-expression resource property defaults by use of the `default` keyword in a resource declaration.

If you wanted to do so, you could push more details of the directory names back into the data with a little more effort (and one or more new keys).

Comment: Working solution for my question! Problem is that a resource type expects a fixed number of arguments. 

Other way: I defined in my "our_mysql::configure_db" <br/>


`$dynamic_mysql_defaults = {
  datadir   => "/data/var/lib/mysql/${dbname}",
  log_error => "/data/var/log/mysql/${dbname}.log",
  logbindir => "/data1/var/lib/mysql/${dbname}", 
}`
<br/>

An merged it with the "+" operator: <br/>

`$db_config = { $dbname => $dynamic_mysql_defaults+$dbdefaults+$dbparams }`
<br/>
This gives more freedom and is a valid compromise. Originally I wanted to speperate code from data.